# PHPlist Campaign HTML Broken comes with e>

Tags: php, html, phplist

I am testing phplist and tried to send campaign. 
In start campaign, I added html code in compose message
It was broken especially these tags

```
 <table> <div> <tr> <strike>
```

The test mail shows in the top "e>" and &nbsp, iv> r> and 
some "text" as "t ext" and then all images normally. Some

```
<a href> on <img> are also not working.
```

After lot of trying I sent one blank message which also had e> printed in email body.

Can anyone help me pointing out where this header part is?
Why html is broken? Please help

Comment: Can we see your whole code ? Easier for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Ok...
I added this in config.php and everything works fine
Thanks for the help friends...

```
define("HTMLEMAIL_ENCODING","8bit");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's related to your PHP version, login to your host cpanel and try a different PHP version. (I.E. from 5.2 to 5.3)